# Consulta acerca de un formulario POST en Python (Flask)

Tags: python, post, flask

Holaa Todos:

Tengo el siguiente código en Python (Flask):

```
@app.route('/del_masivo',methods=['POST'])
def del_masivo():
    Lista = request.form.getlist
    print(Lista)
```

Al ejecutar me muestra lo siguiente:

```
<bound method MultiDict.getlist of ImmutableMultiDict([('Id', '42f6ab44-7940-412f-bd93-6741c370b9bd'), ('Id', '096a5591-cd32-4e5e-932e-fd1977598eb8')])>
```

Necesito obtener el segundo valor de cada par, es decir, para el caso 1, '42f6ab44-7940-412f-bd93-6741c370b9bd'; para el caso 2, '096a5591-cd32-4e5e-932e-fd1977598eb8'

Cómo puedo acceder a cada uno de esos valores...???

Muchas Gracias.

Comment: has un `resultado = [res[1] for res in lista]`

Comment: Para que getlist te de un resultado manejable debes pasarle una key, si con `getlist` intentaste convertirlo en una lista de pares entonces tu lo que necesitas es usar `request.form.items()` que devolverá una lista de la forma `[(x1,y1),(x2,y2)]`

Comment: Hice esto: request.form.getlist("Id") y funcionó...!!!Gracias.

Comment: @PatricioVargas que bueno!, si quieres puedes responder a tu propia pregunta